# sliderman.js - call "go" function from href

Tags: javascript, slider, dom-events

I'm using sliderman.js (http://www.devtrix.net/sliderman/api.html).
The last couple hours I tried to figure out how to call a specific slide from an .
Test but I always get the message that this function is not defined.

Any help is appreciated.

There seems to be a method called Slider.go which is in the file "sliderman.1.3.0.js

```
Slider.go = function(index){
            index = (images.length + index) % images.length;
            autoplay(false);
            if(status != 'free' || current == index) return autoplay(true) && false;
            previous = current;
            current = index;
            eventCall('loading');
            showLoading(true);
            if(contentmode) doEffect(images[current]);
            else loadImage(images[current], doEffect, display.always_show_loading);
            return true;
        }//go
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there you need to call `.go` on the `variable` you use to initialize the slider. For example **[Demo 3](http://www.devtrix.net/sliderman/examples.html)** uses,

```
var demoSlider_3 = Sliderman.slider({container: 'SliderName_3', width: 800, height: 200, effects: effectsDemo3, display: {autoplay: 3000}});
```

So to get it to work on a link for example you can do the following.

```
<a href="#" onclick="demoSlider_3.go(1)">go</a>
```

the number `1` is the id of the slide. I went ahead and tested it locally and it worked every time. You can try it by downloading Demo 3, and adding the link anywhere on the page.